# AWS Api Gateway: Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

So i have a Custom Domain Name setup for api gateway linked to a lambda function.
I have it working fine if i do https://api_domain.com/something the behavior is as expected.

Resource: /{proxy+} 
Base Path Mappings: /

But when i go to the root domain and try to display something for that url i can't get it to work

https://api_domain.com/

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Searching around i found;

> The "Missing Authentication Token" error might be happening if you
>   aren't adding the resource to your uri. For me, browsing to
>   https://{api_domain}/{stage} results in that error. If you do
>   https://{api_domain}/{stage}/{resource_name} then the error may
>   disappear.

Is there a way to display something custom for the root domain or is the only option to display that ugly error?

Comment: **See Also**: [Missing Authentication Token while accessing API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39655048/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to the `/` root resource. As you have discovered the `/{proxy+}` doesn't match the root, you have to handle it separately.