# "Missing Authentication Token" error message, while trying to access public API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating a simple lambda function in AWS and wiring it with API gateway.

The issue, I'm having is that I'm getting "Missing Authentication Token" error response, while trying to reach created resource via HTTP, even I have "Authorization: NONE" defined in resource settings.

Here are the resource details:

[image]

Any reason, why **Authorization** option ignored? Did anyone had similar issue before?

Comment: try HTTPS - double check your URL is correct.  Often times this has happened to me either over HTTP or i spelling error in the URL.

Comment: **See Also**: [Missing Authentication Token while accessing API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39655048/1366033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the correct URL path for your stage. (Also make sure you deployed)

[image]

From the image above is how you can get the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue:
I have a public gateway "GET" API, which is working perfectly if I directly open it from the browser without authorization. But I get the 403 "Missing Authentication Token" error when I called it directly from a Java code:

```java
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", myJWTToken);

String result = getResponse(conn, mapper);
System.out.println(result);
```

But I succeed in Java when I removed that `conn.setDoOutput(true)` line