# Why root returns 403 error in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-api-gateway

I have a very simple lambda function that facilitates short URL redirection. Like so...

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV

exports.handler = async function (event) {
  var mappings = {
    "": "https://example.com",
    "/": "https://example.com",
    "/article1": "https://example.com/articles/article-title",
    "/podcasts": "https://example.com/podcasts"
  }
  return {
    body: null,
    headers: {
      "Location": mappings[event.path] || "https://example.com/four-oh-four"
    },
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 301
  }
}
```

The URL redirects just fine for all routes except the homepage (with or without a slash). Instead of the homepage, I get a "Missing Authentication Token" error from API Gateway (or Cloudfront rather).

Curling doesn't appear to reveal anything... **(Updated the curl code, my bad I left the redirect).**

```
$ curl -v https://short.url/
*   Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to short.url (xxx.xx.xxx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /path/to/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /path/to/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / xxxxxxxxxxxx-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.ib.run
*  start date: Apr  5 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: May  5 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "short.url" matched cert's "short.url"
*  issuer: xxx; O=xxx; OU=xxx; CN=xxx
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle xxxxxxxx)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: short.url
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 403 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 42
< date: Sat, 20 Jul 2019 03:51:44 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
< x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: xxxxx-xx
< x-amz-cf-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx===
< 
* Connection #0 to host short.url left intact
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Comment: Do you have IAM authorization enabled on any of the GET methods for your various resources in API gateway? When I've encountered the 'missing authentication token' error it was because I was trying to call the API without an AWS signature.

Comment: I doubt that. I think it's coming from Cloudfront (API Gateway has a Cloudfront in front of it, and Cloudfront tends to return 403s for everything). Any route other than the root directs just fine.

Comment: The curl doesn't show the auth error?

Comment: Updated the curl command! Sorry about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Authentication Token while accessing API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655048/missing-authentication-token-while-accessing-api-gateway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response **"Missing Authentication Token"** is misleading.
It suggests that you need to provide an Token.
The real error is, that your routes in Api gateway are not setup properly.
So it is basically an **Route not found** from api-gateway.

You need to provide a Route for "/" with a method or the any method and redirect it to the Lambda function. You probably setup an subroute but no route for "/"

[image: Route on /]

At the moment the curl is hitting the url **"/"** with the method GET and Api-Gateway does not know how to route this call so it answers with: **"Missing Authentication Token".**

You can reproduce this behavior with every non existent route. Try: /sdfsdfsdf for example. You will get the same error.

Setup the route and you shoud be fine.

I hope I could help you!

Dominik

Comment: If I go to short.url/sdfsdfsdf, I receive my 404 page, as intended. Updating question...

Comment: It worked! I had a proxy resource, but I just added your any method to the route, and that did the trick. Thank you : )

Comment: @Costa I still get Missing Authentication Token, how do you setup the root?

Comment: @WeijingJayLin wooof. This error can be so tough to track down. Have you posted your question anywhere with details and such?

Comment: @Costa, yes, I do have question over here, nobody pick up yet. I would be appreciated if you can post your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498809/how-can-i-use-proxy-to-handle-the-root-resource-on-api-gateway-to-return-body