# how can I use proxy+ to handle the root resource on api gateway to return body?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

API Gateway with proxy+ works fine for me, the only thing is that the root path always return "Missing Authentication Token", so I found I should setup "ANY" method for the root path, but it would return the response with header in json.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Welcome!\"}",
  "headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "22",
    "etag": "W/\"16-XP9xOOkLTTczHdpNV2DV26X8ykM\"",
    "date": "Tue, 03 Mar 2020 01:15:05 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

how can I get return only the body?

Comment: This should be solvable. Can you put up the code from the server? What's behind the root call on API Gateway? Is there a Lambda function or a server?

Comment: @Costa it is from lambda. Currently, I'm using proxy+, it will filter out everything but only return the body (amazing, and why?!), but proxy+ won't cover the case for  root path, aka "/".

Comment: Got it. Can you share your Lambda code?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, we could just use proxy when we setup the "get" (or "any") method on root.

[image]

if you have already setup the on the method, you update it on integration request

[image]

Comment: This one works for me. My /{proxy+} ANY resource was already tied to a lambda proxy, and setting up "Create Method" > / GET with the same proxy integration did the trick.