# {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} while accessing lambda through API end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am able to call the URL end point through POSTMAN which is invoking a lambda function.

But when i am trying to use the end point through browser it is giving me bow json object.
i feel API gateway is blocking it. I dont have any authorization set for the end point as you can see below

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

[image]

I have this above setting.
wondering what is causing this?

i have similar lambda integration is "/call" resource which has GET method which is working fine both in POSTMAN and WEB.

Could anyone let me know the issue.
I am properly using PUT method or i am on the correct path or the issue with code that i used with **LAMBDA**. Currently no clue

Comment: Could you describe how you call it in browser?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `PUT` as your HTTP method when you call? That error is typically thrown when the endpoint you are requesting does not exist. /insert only has a PUT method, not a GET method.

Comment: @jellycsc i am using the invoke URL that is been generated by the Test stage.
I usually click on PUT method and get he invoke URL and past it on the browser tab

Comment: @Chris I am using Lambda as an integration type  for PUT. 
GET method is placed under "/call" resource

Comment: How are you sending the request, this sometimes happens when the call is hitting a route that does not exist.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams i am just pasting the url in the browser and adding the query parameter to it .
when i try it on POSTMAN it is working

Comment: @ChrisWilliams for some reason the API gateway is not able to invoke the lambda. don't know if i need to add anything along the request

Comment: How did it [work with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894455/messagemissing-authentication-token-while-accessing-lambda-through-api-en#comment111313899_62894455), if [API Gateway can't invoke Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894455/messagemissing-authentication-token-while-accessing-lambda-through-api-en#comment111313945_62894455)?

Comment: @cellepo I am able to to run the test in api gateway as well . it is working fine there. 
when i past in browser it's not . I feel i am missing any header or key ,but i haven't set any for api

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it does not work in the browser? How are you invoking a PUT request from a browser?

Comment: @Subash I am just going ahead and pasting the invocation URL  in the browser with query parameters.