# AWS Lambda function works with when I test in Postman, but when I try to implement in my ReactJS I get status code 500

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I working with ReactJS trying to create a contact form using AWS Lambda and SES.  I was following this [guide](https://dev.to/adnanrahic/building-a-serverless-contact-form-with-aws-lambda-and-aws-ses-4jm0) for the AWS setup. When I send my json file using postman I have no issues status 200 and the email sends, great! then I try to implement it in my React file and I have issues. despite having the same API endpoint.

```
function post(url, body, callback) {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("POST", url, true);
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      req.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (req.status < 400) {
          callback(null, JSON.parse(req.responseText));
        } else {
          callback(new Error("Request failed: " + req.statusText));
        }
      });
      req.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
```

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.state.form);
      post(url, this.state.form, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          return alert(err);
        }
        alert("success");
      });
    };
```

the response I get from AWS:

```
{
message: "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

I've tried these steps [AWS lessons on missing token](http://www.awslessons.com/2017/aws-api-gateway-missing-authentication-token/)

[image: Postman]

I have checked the url 1000 times and unless I'm missing something it is correct.
Invoke URL: https://EXAMPLE.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/email/send

also tried everything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655048/missing-authentication-token-while-accessing-api-gateway)

Not sure what I have wrong and why postman works but my code doesn't any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
req.withCredentials = true;
```

Reference: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: req.withCredentials = false;  Was the actual solution for me here, not really sure why but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!