# AWS post request works on postman but not react-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway

This is my JS code for the API

```
export const getUser = async (user) => {
    //Working
    const json = await fetch( "*****/username/getUser", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user:user
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error in getUser: " + err);
      });
    return json;
  };
```

Here is an attempt to make the request, which unfortunately return the authentication error.

```
    fetchUser.request("kirolosM")
    .then((result)=>{  
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log("Error ",err);})
```

The error

```
{
  "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

I have tested the API using postman and it is working as expexted.

Comment: You should not share your endpoints in public for security reasons.

Comment: You're absolutely right... sorry about that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Authentication Token while accessing API Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655048/missing-authentication-token-while-accessing-api-gateway)

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it didn't.
Ended up ditching the whole project and started from scratch... Somehow that worked
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably useful to compare the request sent from your json code to the one you're sending from postman.  It looks like you need to include you auth token in your headers in your request.

Something like

```
export const getUser = async (user) => {
    //Working
    const json = await fetch( "*****/username/getUser", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authentication": `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      ...
```